# Select value changes but visible option selected does not

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with WordPress by overriding the `cart-shipping.php` file (WooCommerce). After filling a select with options:

```
<?php
if (strpos($chosen_method, 'pickup_') !== false) {
    printf('<li><select name="select" id="method_pickups" onchange="handlePickup()">');
    foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
        printf('<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>');
    }
    printf('</select></li>');
}
?>
```

I want to set the selected value by getting one stored on the session storage using javascript like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const method_pickups = document.querySelector('#method_pickups');
    method_pickups.value = sessionStorage.getItem('method_pickups_soda');
    handlePickup();
});

const handlePickup = () => {
    const method_pickups = document.querySelector('#method_pickups');
    const billing_pickups = document.querySelector('#billing_pickups');
    sessionStorage.setItem('method_pickups_soda', method_pickups.value);

    if (!window.location.href.includes('carrito')) {
        billing_pickups.value = method_pickups.value;

        const index = method_pickups.selectedIndex;
        const display = document.querySelector('#display_pickup');
        display.value = method_pickups.options[index].text;
    }
};
```

The problem is that even though the value its being changed (cause a simple `console.log()` displays the new value) it is visually the same option. What is going on in here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: But it gets the value. If I log the value of `method_pickups_soda` it displays what is stored. The code even changes the value of the select. The only thing that doesn't work right now is the visual part. It sticks with the older option even though the value is different.

Comment: @Pointy I just added my `handlePickup()` function to the question.

Comment: OK sorry I misread the code; I'll delete my earlier comment.

Comment: Needless to say, this should and does work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h7rfsekz/ We need to see the final code, not the PHP source, and we need to see the value you're trying to set. The first order of debugging is to put `console.log()` commands everywhere to make sure a) your code is called b) variables contain what you think they contain

Comment: That's part of the problem. I'v created a code with nothing but a select with some options, changed the value by using the same code and it works just fine. I think this is a wordpress-related problem but I can't see what's happening.

Comment: You need to go to this site: https://new.sodastream.com.ar/carrito/ and put some items in your car. The select is in the right side of the page labeled as "Punto Pickup"

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah Chris, I've try this logging everywhere method and everything looks just fine. All the values are being set perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was about an ajax request being in process which prevented the change. In order to solve my problem I waited for it to be finished:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    const method_pickups = document.querySelector('#method_pickups');
    method_pickups.value = sessionStorage.getItem('method_pickups_soda');
    handlePickup();
});
```